Sort objects in a set by separate parameter instead of key
Given a class called "SortableRecord" that has an ID to determine uniqueness in the set and a value to determine the order in the set, how can I achieve the following:
SortedSet<SortableRecord> coll = new TreeSet<>();
coll.add(new SortableRecord("a", 10.0));
coll.add(new SortableRecord("a", 11.0));
coll.add(new SortableRecord("a", 300.0));
coll.add(new SortableRecord("b", 11.0));
coll.add(new SortableRecord("b", 41.0));

assertEquals(2, coll.size());

There should only be two objects in the set. The object with ID b should come first as its value is 41 and object a ID is 300.

Can it be that you missinterpret the concept of sorting and equals? If you add 5 distinct entries to a set, there will be 5 entries in the set. That has nothing to do with sorting. Besides, you refer to a key, but there is no key involved at all. Keys usually come with a value, called key-value pairs, and are used eg in Maps.

@Slevin I would like to index the values for fast lookup and retrieve the keys. Sounds like I will need a map holding the inverse.

You can also build your own data structure, where you can preprocess the entries at your preference. Anyhow, I still don't know what exactly your aim is. I think you wanna keep the entry with the highest value for a given string. Map#computeIfPresent could be a way to get it done and you wouldn't even need a dedicated SortableRecord for that.

You need a custom collection type, a custom element type alone won't do you so much if the collection data structure doesn't meet your needs.

Looks like I am interested in a SortedMap where the map is sorted by the values.

Looks like I am interested in a SortedMap where the map is sorted by the values. You got it, now do it ;)

I don't get it. If you have a class named as such then it would be Comparable and equals based on its ID. (Non-) problem solved!

It's not clear what you mean - do you wish to keep the last id match added or rank same id by highest? So if first add was SortableRecord("a", 1000.0) do you expect set to contain b/41 and a/1000?

@Slevin a TreeSet doesn't quite conform to a Set unless the compareTo is constent with the equals. ie if compareTo returns 0 the objects are deemed equal.

@matt As we already elaborated, the data structure in question shall either be a custom one or, imo better, as long it fits the questioner's not further specified requirements, a TreeMap. A set, respectively a TreeSet seems not to be a thing to get the job done.

@DuncG if the last value with "a" added is 1000 and the last value with "b" added was 41, yes.

@Slevin I agree about their solution. I wanted to point out your first comment separates  sorting and equals which is correct for the Set api, but isn't true for a TreeSet. I thought it should be noted.

@Slevin the SortedMap interface's subMap method takes this form: SortedMap<K, V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey); This interface doesn't work exactly. I would like: SortedMap<K, V> subMap(V fromVal, V toVal); Custom class incoming...

You need to re-think what collection you want, as you can't use Set this way - see Set.add. While you could define equals/hashCode to ensure 3x"a"s are equivalent, calling add 5 times means set only contains the first of "a/10.0" and first "b/11". If you don't change equals/hashCode then the set will have 5 elements. Neither outcome is consistent with your question.

I'm unsure what you want, but here is a streaming solution to generate a distinctly sorted collection.
public record SortableRecord(String key, double value){

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<SortableRecord> source = Stream.of(new SortableRecord("a", 10.0),
                new SortableRecord("b", 11.0),
                new SortableRecord("a", 300.0),
                new SortableRecord("a", 11.0),
                new SortableRecord("b", 41.0));

        var coll = source.collect(Collectors.toMap(SortableRecord::key, Function.identity(),
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(SortableRecord::value, Double::compare))))
                .values();

        System.out.println(coll);
    }
}

